# CentOS 7 - running FFMPEG as a service

Tags: centos, systemd

I'm writing some tests for a video streaming project.
In order to check that I stream video correctly, I've set up a VM that runs a video client (e.g ffmpeg / vlc) as a daemon. I want that, on command, the client will connect to the server, display the video and save the video to a file.

In order to do that, I've set a service. Here is my .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Video client for testing

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/
ExecStart=client.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Ideally, I want this to be a user service. Sadly, my VM runs CentOS 7 which [can not run user services](https://superuser.com/a/1121451). As a regular service, the $DISPLAY and $XAUTHORITY needs to be set as well, but I couldn't find any script that initializes them like [in arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#DISPLAY_and_XAUTHORITY) so I don't think it will be healthy to set them up myself. I'm also not sure how this is going to work if login is not automatic. The script itself does not work well even with just saving the video and not opening a graphical window. It does work well when launching it

I've been thinking of running the script from a .profile, but I don't like this idea too much, it seems awkward (or sure if that is even a good option).
Another option would be to set up the script via SSH (for example, using [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) - which requires additional dependencies / scripts.

I would really appreciate some suggestions / alternatives / ways of action, since I don't want it to hack this too much.

Thanks,
Joey.

Comment: Which version of `systemd` do you have installed? VLC daemon mode runs the web interface, but it sounds like you want to runt the VLC client automatically. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I recommend is to not `systemd` but instead set a user to automatically login, and use your desktops "autostart" feature to automatically launch VLC at at login and start trying to stream the content.

This approach will handle setting $DISPLAY AND $XAUTHORITY for you.

This pattern is commonly used on Raspberry Pi kiosk projects, where users want to automatically have a browser automatically launch and open a URL fullscreen after the device boots.